# Problems working with a Wordpress site on a local server

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to download a large Wordpress site and work on it locally. I exported/imported the SQL successfully using PHPMyAdmin w/ XAMPP, and changed the wp-config.php file to match my MySQL login information and I'm no longer getting "Error establishing a database connection". As far as I know, the schemas and imported information should all be good to go, but I am getting a 404 Error on the main page. Is there anywhere else I might need to update the database settings?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: migrating wordpress is a right pain. You need to go through the database and change all references to the old domain and change it to your localhost. It's really not fun :)

Comment: @Chris Till - there is really no need to manually go through the DB :-) See the answer for a 1 min. update that is fast (and fun ?? ) :-)

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Oh cool. I'll have to remember that for next time.

Comment: Yes you need to set local url (path) in wp-option table

Answer (score 1):

you will need to update your DB like so :

Update new location >

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

Fix URLs and Post slugs >

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');
```

Then fix internal links >

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.old-domain.com', 'http://www.new-domain.com');
```

In your case `http://www.new-domain.com` would be  `http://localhost`  or `http://localhost/your_wp_install_folder/`

After running this , just to make sure , go to your DB and check the options table for the `siteurl` and `home` options, and see that they really do point to the right place ...